# Can the PowerMac G5 support a 2TB drive

Tags: mac, hard-drive, upgrade

Only answer if:

- you have tested this yourself or seen it work.
- can provide a link to strong evidence that it will work.

Please no "should work" answers, I know it should work.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.mactalk.com.au/10/74648-powermac-g5-2tb-hd.html) there will be an issue.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that link too, he may be right but evidence is anecdotal .

Comment: I am inclined to agree http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1587734 shows a 1.5 in use.

Comment: I have some experience from writing SCSI controller drivers, and the LBA limit is usually determined by the protocol itself, e.g a 32-bit number is used for block addressing (still 32-bit == 2TB of 512 sectors). Not sure if newer HDs use a 4K sector size and that it could be a factor?

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer my own question. YES the PowerMac G5 supports 2TB drives. I installed 2x2TB Western Digital drives in my PowerMac G5 Dual 1.8 Ghz in a RAID-1 configuration.